# Which debugging tool (if any) allows me to identify the thread that is holding a lock on a file?

Tags: .net, io, ioexception, sos, file-locking

I'm debugging a test that periodically raises an `IOException`, noting that a file can not be deleted because it is being used by another process.  I suspect that the process is indeed my test harness, and that some other thread in the process hasn't disposed of its file resources when I expected it to.

Is there a tool that I can use to determine which thread holds the impeding lock?  If I can identify the thread, then I can inspect its call stack and at least try to determine why the resource is not yet disposed.  The [SOS debugging tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) looks promising, but I don't see any feature that would remove a fair amount of guesswork from my investigation.

One thought is to identify the native OS thread-ID, which then can be mapped to a managed thread ID via SOS.  How would I accomplish the former?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Process Explorer from the SysInternals tools. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653
Just open it and search for your file name. it will show you what processes have a lock on it.

---

*Edit:*

Oh I just re-read that and noticed you asked for the specific thread. I dont know if ProcessExplorer can do that. Sorry!

---

*Edit 2:*

A second answer, that expands on agent-j's answer:

If you can edit the code and add a try/catch around it to get the IOException, you can also log the stack trace, since it sounds like that is what you want to inspect:

```
catch(IOException)
{
    LogMessage( string.Format(
        "Managed Thread Id: {0}",
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) );

    LogMessage( string.Format(
        "Stack Trace: {0}",
        new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).ToString()) );
}
```

---

*Edit 3*

Using the approach above, you could also log the threads and stack traces for all threads in the process, making it easier to look through a log and figure out what happened postmortem.  Updated code:

```
catch(IOException)
{
  foreach (var thread in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
  {
    LogMessage(string.Format(
      "Managed Thread Id: {0}",
      thread.ManagedThreadId));

    LogMessage(string.Format(
      "Stack Trace: {0}",
      new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(thread, true).ToString()));

  }
}
```

Comment: ... and if you point it at your symbols, you can see the threads and get stack traces.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however this will isolate the call stack of the thread that caught the exception.  I'm interested in identifying the thread that is holding the lock, which is not generally not the same.  However, I may need to resort to agent-j's solution.

Comment: @Steve Guidi - You could also use my approach above to dump a stack trace for all threads in the process.  I haven't actually tested this but I think it would work.  See my latest edit above...

Answer (score 2):

If you put a breakpoint in a `try{delete();}catch(IOException)` catch clause.  Can't you then look at the callstack of each thread?

Comment: If you are at the exception catch in VisualStudio, then opening the 'Threads' view (`Debug | Windows | Threads`, from the main menu), then it should show a yellow arrow next to your current thread, which should be the same one that caught the exception.

Comment: Yes, I could.  I may have to resort to this and this could get laborious as there may be several threads running at the time.

Comment: I have heard that FxCop (at compile time) can find some disposable problems in code.  Have you considered this?

Answer (score 0):

Threads do not hold locks on files (at least not as the operating system is concerned).  Consider the following example.  The thread `t` creates a file and locks the file.  The main thread writes to the stream and closes it.  This shows that the thread doesn't own the lock.  The process does.

```
     Stream stream = null;
     Thread t = new Thread(() => stream = File.OpenWrite (@"c:\temp\junk111.txt"));
     t.Start();
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
     Console.WriteLine(t.ThreadState);
     stream.WriteByte(89);
     stream.Close();
     File.OpenWrite (@"c:\temp\junk222.txt");
```

Prints `stopped`, so the thread that opened the file is not running anymore, but the file handle it created is still open.

Here is the relevant part of result of FxCop for the above file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop>FxCopCmd.exe /file:c:\code\jeremy.sellars\test\Junk\bin\Debug\Junk.exe /console
Microsoft (R) FxCop Command-Line Tool, Version 10.0 (10.0.30319.1) X86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, All Rights Reserved.

...
[Location not stored in Pdb] : warning  : CA2210 : Microsoft.Design : Sign 'Junk.exe' with a strong name key.
C:\code\jeremy.sellars\TEST\Junk\Program.cs(50,1) : warning  : CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'Program.Main()', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'File.OpenWrite("c:\\temp\\junk2.txt")' before all references to it are out of scope.
Done:00:00:06.1251568

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop>
```